# Eloquent relationship returning all when ID doesn't match

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For some reason my relationship is fetching all from the corresponding table when I dump it, however dumping the result does not show these rows.

The `slider` ID does not match the `slider_id` within the `settings` table.

So the following works fine, as expected the settings is an empty array:

```
/**
 * @return HasOne
 */
public function slider(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Slider::class)->withDefault(
        (new Slider())->attributesToArray()
    );
}

Result:
{
  "name": "media-slider",
  "settings": []
}
```

However when I dump within the attribute I get all the rows from the settings table, when this query should be getting all settings where the `slider_id` matches the current slider, which has a different ID.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Media;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class Slider extends Model
{

    /** @var string[] */
    protected $appends = [ 'settings' ];

    protected $defaults = [
        'test' => [
            'id' => 0,
            'name' => 'default name',
        ]
    ];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->attributes = $this->defaults['test'];
    }


    /**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function settings(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SliderSetting::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the slider settings, extract the value and key by the key, also
     * group if multiple setting groups are required.
     *
     * Perform this logic here so data can be used directly by the JavaScript.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|Collection
     */
    public function getSettingsAttribute()
    {
        dd($this->settings()->get()); // This should be empty! 
        return $this->settings()->get()
            ->groupBy('group')
            ->map(static function ($group) {
                $group = $group->keyBy('key');
                return $group->map(static function ($setting) {
                    return $setting->getAttribute('value');
                });
            });
    }
}
```

## Edit

```
/**
 * @return HasMany
 */
public function sliderSettings(): HasMany
{
    dd($this->hasMany(SliderSetting::class)->toSql());
    return $this->hasMany(SliderSetting::class);
}
```

The above outputs:

> select * from `slider_settings`

Shouldn't it be the following?

> select * from `slider_settings` where `slider_settings`.`slider_id` = ?

Comment: What do you get for `dd($this->settings)` in getSettingsAttribute()

Comment: @Donkarnash I do get null, however I PHPStorm gives me the `accessed by magic` warning which I hate seeing so not sure if there is a better way I can do this without that warning?

Comment: You can try to use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper package which will help you get rid of most warnings in IDEs

Comment: In-fact just changed my `slider` id to match the `slider_id` within my `settings` table and it's still null, but now this should have rows.

Comment: @Donkarnash running `$this->settings()->get()` appears to get ALL rows, it's not taking into account the relationship at all.

Comment: @Donkarnash see updated post

Comment: Yes the generated sql is not quite right - strange. Can you try to delete vendor folder and cum composer install again

Comment: @Donkarnash Deleted and ran install and still same query :S

Comment: Can you upload it to a public repo on github and post the link  - can then try to clone and test

Comment: Figured it out, it's because I set the `id` in my `slider` model to hidden -_- I just assumed this meant it wouldn't dump this out, not make it un-usable by relationships!